# Python/flask making sure a value is passed in

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I am trying to do is if a user inputs nothing or anything else than a positive int, it gives an error. Somehow if the user inputs nothing the error doesn't show. How can I disallow empty input?

```
    # get positive number of shares user wants to buy
    shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
    if shares is None or shares < 0:
        return apology("Please make sure that the shares you are buying is more than 0")
```

Comment: Is zero a valid value? I would expect `request.form.get("shares")` to not return a valid integer if nothing was passed. Maybe it's returning `0` which would pass your check as it is not `None` and is not less than `0`

Comment: If you want to ensure a positive int, then check for it.  You want `or shares < 1`, not `or shares < 0`.  As your code is written, 0 is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 is neither a positive nor negative number. You may need to change your code into this:

```py
shares = request.form.get("shares", 0)  # set default to 0 if input is empty
if int(shares) <= 0:
    return apology("Please make sure that the shares you are buying is more than 0")
```

However, you may need to use `try ... except` statement when converting string into integer:

```py
shares = request.form.get("shares", 0)  # set default to 0 if input is empty

try:
   shares_int = int(shares)
except ValueError:
   shares_int = 0

if shares_int <= 0:
    return apology("Please make sure that the shares you are buying is more than 0")
```